# Как переключаться между окнами при помощи кнопок на Toolbar?

Tags: python, kivy

При помощи обычной кнопки я могу переключиться между двумя окнами, задав им команду app.root.current = 'имя окна' и небольшую анимацию, в какую сторону будет перемещаться окно (root.manager.transition.direction). Я реализовал смену окон для кнопочки Toolbar, однако задать ей через обычный метод анимацию я не могу. Подскажите, как это сделать

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class WindowChoose(Screen): # начальное окно
    pass

class WindowInfoConvert(Screen): # конвертация величин информации
    pass

class WindowWeightConvert(Screen): # конвертация массы
    pass

class WindowTemperatureConvert(Screen): # конвертация градусов
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager): # поддержка всех окон
    pass

class ConvertApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(window_convert)

    def back(self):
        self.root.current = 'choose'


window_convert = '''
WindowManager:
    WindowChoose:
    WindowInfoConvert:

<MyButton@MDFlatButton>:
    font_size: 20
    size_hint_y: None
    size_hint_x: root.width

<WindowChoose>:
    name: 'choose'
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'    
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'Конвертер'
            left_action_items: [['menu']]
        ScrollView:    
            MDGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                height: self.minimum_height
                size_hint_y: None  
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Информация'
                    on_release: 
                        app.root.current = 'info_convert'
                        root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Масса'
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Расстояние'
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Площадь'
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Объем'
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Время'
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Давление'
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Количество теплоты'
                    
<WindowInfoConvert>:
    name: 'info_convert'
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'    
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'Количество информации'
            left_action_items: [['arrow-left', lambda x: app.back()]]
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Здесь что-то будет'
            font_size: 32
            halign: 'center'
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ConvertApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно здесь нужно self.root.manager.transition.direction = 'right' в функции изменить на self.root.transition.direction = 'right'